# Private submodules not found on Travis CI

Tags: git, ssh, travis-ci, git-submodules

I'm part of an organisation that has a git repository with several submodules that are private as well. This is what our `.gitmodules` looks like:

```
[submodule "app/modules/confetti"]
    path = app/modules/confetti
    url = https://<username>:<personal-access-token>@github.com:MyOrganisation/Confetti-module.git
[submodule "app/modules/balloons"]
    path = app/modules/balloons
    url = https://<username>:<personal-access-token>@github.com:MyOrganisation/Balloons-module.git
```

On my local machine I can update, init or clone these submodules just fine. However, when I let Travis CI run, it throws an error:

```
Cloning into 'app/modules/confetti'...
fatal: repository 'https://<username>:<personal-access-token>@github.com:MyOrganisation/Confetti-module.git/' not found
Clone of 'https://<username>:<personal-access-token>@github.com:MyOrganisation/Confetti-module.git' into submodule path 'app/modules/confetti' failed
```

I have already tried removing the credentials from the url, using the SSH url and adding my SSH key to Travis. None of these solutions solves my problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at the Private Dependencies doc page, I think the [Password option](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/#Password) is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Already tried that one. Doesn't work either :(